# Show that $φ$, built by joining subformulas $θ_1, θ_2, . . . , θ_n$ with $∧$, is true for those truth assignments which make each subformulas true.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, induction

> Suppose that the formula $φ$ is constructed by taking subformulas $θ_1, θ_2, . . . , θ_n$ in that order and joining them together only using the connective $∧$, with brackets inserted in such a way as to make $φ$ a formula. Show that $φ$ is true precisely for those truth assignments which make each of the subformulas
>   $θ_1, θ_2, . . . , θ_n$ true. Deduce that any two such formulas (using the same $θ_1, θ_2, . . . , θ_n$ in that order) are logically equivalent. [Hint: Use the version of mathematical induction with the hypothesis that the result holds for all $k ≤ n$ where $n ≥ 1$.]
>
> Examples for $n = 4$ include
>   $((θ_1 ∧ θ_2) ∧ (θ_3 ∧ θ_4))$ and
>   $(θ_1 ∧ ((θ_2 ∧ θ_3) ∧ θ_4))$.
>
> ps. I am also given that $(φ ∧ (ψ ∧ θ)) ≡ ((φ ∧ ψ) ∧ θ)$ and $((θ_1 ∧ θ_2) ∧ (θ_3 ∧ θ_4)) ≡ (θ_1 ∧ ((θ_2 ∧ θ_3) ∧ θ_4))$, but I suspect this has more to do with the logic equivalance part.

My induction is as detailed below; however while it should include example like $(θ_1 ∧ ((θ_2 ∧ θ_3) ∧ θ_4))$, it doesn't seem to account for $((θ_1 ∧ θ_2) ∧ (θ_3 ∧ θ_4))$. For the latter, instead of adding on subformula one by one (eg. from $θ_1 ∧ θ_2$ to $(θ_1 ∧ θ_2) ∧ θ_3$), it adds on two at a time (ie conjuncting $(θ_3 ∧ θ_4)$ onto $(θ_1 ∧ θ_2)$ - but my proof only seems to be able to account for cases where subformulas are built upon each other one by one.

Unless of course, if I treat $(θ_3 ∧ θ_4)$ as a subformula in itself, then my induction would then still be adding on one subformula at a time. But I am not sure if this is legit.
Could anyone verify if my proof is ok please?

Also could anyone please give me some hint on how to proceed with the logical equivalance proof please? Thank you so much!

---

Induction on number of subformulas:

Base case: let $n=1$. Then $φ=θ_1$, therefore $v(θ_1)=T=v(φ)$.

Inductive step: assume that the property holds for all $k\le n$, show that it holds also for $k=n+1$. ie. $φ=((θ_1\land ...θ_n)\landθ_{n+1})$.

The property holds for $(θ_1\land ...θ_n)$ and we have assumed that $v(θ_{n+1})=T$ (because we need to show that $φ$ is true when we have a truth assignment that makes all subformulas true), couple with the fact that $v(φ)$ is a truth assignment that respects the truth table of $\land$, $v(θ_1\land ...θ_n)=v(θ_{n+1})=v(((θ_1\land ...θ_n)\landθ_{n+1}))=T$

Comment: If you know that $\wedge$ is associative, then how the subformulae are parenthesised doesn't matter.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Is it because I can substitute formulae so that they will somehow fit into $(φ ∧ (ψ ∧ θ)) ≡ ((φ ∧ ψ) ∧ θ)$, so that EVERY variation of subformulae for a given $n$ are all logically equivalent? eg. For $((θ_1 ∧ θ_2) ∧ (θ_3 ∧ θ_4))$, substitute $(θ_1 ∧ θ_2)$ for $φ$ and $(θ_3 ∧ θ_4)$ for $(ψ ∧ θ)$ so that it becomes $(φ ∧ (ψ ∧ θ))$, and likewise fit $(θ_1 ∧ ((θ_2 ∧ θ_3) ∧ θ_4))$ into $((φ ∧ ψ) ∧ θ)$ by the same method?

Comment: I guess so, but that's not quite what I was getting at. Using the fact that $\wedge$ is associative, you can associate all parentheses to the left, so that every expression formed as the conjunction of $n$ subformulae $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n$ is uniquely expressible in the form $$((\cdots(\varphi_1 \wedge \varphi_2) \wedge \cdots ) \wedge \varphi_{n-1}) \wedge \varphi_n$$ This then makes it so that your induction step works just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much @CliveNewstead! I looked in Wikipedia and it said associativity allows rearranging parentheses without affecting the value and that really cleared things up. But to apply associativity to my induction proof, it seems that we need to prove that associativity applies to subformulae of any length (since we are only given associativity which covers $n=3$ and $n=4$) - is this done by substituting the subformulae to fit into the associativity formula (like what I did above)?

Comment: Sorry one more question...for the 2nd part of the question which concerns proving logical equivalence could I simply say that, for two given formulae with the same $n$ and constructed according to the how the question described, their subformulae are the same and thus share the same truth assignments for those subformulae. Therefore in virtue of the result we have for 1st part, the two formulae should also have the same truth value. Is that ok?